# Swift what should I do to add an image at the corner of a button

Tags: ios, swift

this is what i would like to do

[image]

when user click on the image, i show that "yes" image, when he click again, i remove that "yes" image.

What should i do to add that image above the button?
should i implement a custom button? (if yes how can i add the image to that custom button)

should I not use button from the first place? (if yes what should i use?)

your help is highly appreciated

i look to other question but sound like they want to set a custom background for the image like adding a star but i want to keep the text of the button and add that image where i can hide it and show it on an action for that button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better solution is to create a custom UIButton.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    var rightImageView:UIImageView?

    @IBInspectable var rightImage:UIImage? {
        didSet {
            updateImage()
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        createImageViewIfNeeded()
    }

    private func updateImage() {
        if rightImage != nil && rightImageView != nil {
            rightImageView!.image = rightImage!
        }
    }

    private func createImageViewIfNeeded() {
        if rightImageView == nil {
            let rightImageWidth:CGFloat = 30.0
            let imageViewFrame = CGRect(x: self.frame.width - rightImageWidth, y: 0, width: rightImageWidth, height: self.frame.height)
            rightImageView = UIImageView(frame: imageViewFrame)
            rightImageView!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

            self.addSubview(rightImageView!)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: wow wow wow wow wow i wish i could up vote all my life

Answer (score -1):

You can set the `UIImageView` below the `UIButton`, then activate the `UserInteractionEnabled` for the `UIImageView`, add an `UITapGestureRecognizer` to handle the interaction with the `UIImageView` and make an `IBAction` to the `UITapGestureRecognizer` in your `UIViewController` and every time the `UIImageView` is tapped the method is called and inside you can hide/unhide the `UIButton` as you like.

It's just a way to solve your problem, there are many more.

I hope this help you.